# Split string into a hash?

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I have the following example string:

```
"email=bob@example.com&user_id=13&last_seen=January 14, 2013"
```

And I need is converted to a hash:

```
{ :email=>bob@example.com, :user_id=>13, :last_seen => 'January 14, 2013' }
```

How can I do that? The keys and values could be anything (they won't always be `email` and `user_id`) and there could be dozens of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [CGI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) library you already get for free:

```
require 'cgi'

parsed = CGI.parse("email=bob@example.com&user_id=13&last_seen=January 14, 2013")

# => {"email"=>["bob@example.com"], "user_id"=>["13"], "last_seen"=>["January 14, 2013"]}
```

Or if you're using [rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Utils.html):

```
require 'rack/utils'

parsed = Rack::Utils.parse_query("email=bob@example.com&user_id=13&last_seen=January 14, 2013")

# => {"email"=>"bob@example.com", "user_id"=>"13", "last_seen"=>"January 14, 2013"}
```

Comment: Nice thing I have learned today from here, 2 new libraries. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "email=bob@example.com&user_id=13&last_seen=January 14, 2013"
Hash[*str.split(/=|&/)]
```

If you're in Rails you can symbolize keys with `Hash#symbolize_keys`, else you can do it yourself.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the second one over the first? The first seems to work fine with my example string.

Comment: @Shpigford: The first is the real answer, the method you should actually used. The second answer is here to teach you `Hash[ ]` syntax and `String#split` method. Note, however, that parsing, even parsing a single line, is a task beyond the simple methods like `split`.

Answer (score 0):

How about the below :

```
require 'uri'

str = "email=bob@example.com&user_id=13&last_seen=January 14, 2013"
URI.decode_www_form(str)
# => [["email", "bob@example.com"],
#     ["user_id", "13"],
#     ["last_seen", "January 14, 2013"]]
Hash[URI.decode_www_form(str)]
# => {"email"=>"bob@example.com",
#     "user_id"=>"13",
#     "last_seen"=>"January 14, 2013"}
```